# Interval doesn't execute every 5 seconds

Tags: node.js, azure-cosmosdb

```
setInterval(async () => {
    var time = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
    const { result: newevents } = await client.database("database").container("collection").items.query(`SELECT * FROM Events c WHERE c._ts >= ${time - 5} AND c._ts < ${time}`, { enableCrossPartitionQuery: true }).toArray();

    newevents.forEach((element) => {
        redisClientEventData.set(element.id, JSON.stringify(element));
    });        
}, 5000);
```

I'm running this code every 5 seconds to get events from cosmosdb in a 5 second window, and the database query usually only takes 40-60ms. However, over time it will skip a second and miss events. Is there anyway to guarantee I can get every event, every 5 seconds? I tried a while loop but didn't seem to work. This generally will work for 6-12 hours but then skip a second.

I'm expecting to see something like

1553786056

1553786061

1553786066

1553786071

But overtime I'm eventually seeing

1553786056

1553786061

1553786067

1553786072

Comment: Is any other job or tasks running on the same node process?

Comment: No, this is the only thing. I just omitted the requires above that.

Comment: This seems to tackle your exact problem  https://www.npmjs.com/package/accurate-interval . "Create an accurate interval that does not skew over time."

Comment: How do you log time? use `console.log` or log in the database?

Comment: @canon do you have a code example of this?

Comment: @ThatBrianDude - I think this is going to work for me

Comment: So why does native node setinterval not just use something that is similar to that accurate-interval module?

Comment: Probably because it has to have the same behaviour as the legacy setInterval from the browser.

Comment: Accurate interval will still sometimes show something like 1554134878001, 1554134878999, 1554134880000 and causing me to miss the 1554134879000. I added some adjustment to the module but I'm now wondering why this won't accurately get the next interval.

Comment: @acarlstein ... Maybe read the previous comments?